# Looking for a java image that runs with arm and amd64 (multi-architecture)

Tags: java, docker, apple-m1

We recently ran into an issue in that not all java images run on an ARM operating system for MAC (m1). Our last java version for our docker image is 13, and the image we are currently using is: openjdk:13-jdk-alpine.

Does anyone have any recommendations as to which image we should use? We already have a bunch of Linux servers already using our current image.  We just want to enable the M1 machine without breaking everything else.

Comment: Since a Docker image includes the (platform-specific) JVM bundled into it, you can't have a "portable" or "multi-architecture" image.  But a long-standing goal of Java itself is to be an architecture-neutral language runtime; can you install Java on your hosts, instead of Docker, and use that?

Comment: No, it needs to be run from a docker image. We were under the impression that in here: https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags&page=1, we could find an image that supports a linux and Arm OS, but there are a ton of options

Answer (score 2):

openjdk 17.0.1 works on amd64 and arm(m1) (openjdk:17.0.1)
https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/17.0.1/images/sha256-8a99742c7c38a7b0826c8a47cacbca18af5c3a60e6eba18e75d6a8c28b9fa9b4?context=explore

I currently don't know any alpine linux based docker image that is also available for arm.
If you need to use alpine linux and are fine with jdk 16 you can just start `FROM alpine:edge`
and `RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk16`